# Cant find the problem an express server problem

Tags: javascript, html, express

i have an express server which has the code:

```js
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();
/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('website'));

const port = 8000;
// Setup Server
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

  app.get('/all', sendData);
  function sendData (req, res) {
      res.send(projectData);
  };
app.post('/all', receiveData);
function receiveData (req, res) {
  projectData.temp = req.body.temp;
  projectData.date = req.body.date;
  projectData.ures = req.body.ures;
  res.send(projectData);
  console.log(projectData);
}
```

so simply i am making a weather journal app which receives data from an API and shows it to the user and this is the index look like:
[image: index.html file]

so basically the user is going to write the zip code and feelings and when clicking on the button generate the entry should contain the information like this
[image: This is how it should look like]

but when the user click the button generate this shows and the user have to click it again in order to show the information like the top picture:
[image: this is whats happen when the user click generate one time]

and this is the JavaScript code for the client-side:

```js
/* Global Variables */
let baseURLz = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';
let baseURLa = '&appid=';
const apiKey = '8e017daef09d7f784c8595696bdcb587';

// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){
const zipcode = document.getElementById('zip').value;
const ures = document.getElementById('feelings').value;


getWeather(baseURLz, zipcode, baseURLa, apiKey)
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    postData('/all', {temp: data.main.temp, date: newDate, ures: ures});
})
.then(
    updateUI()
)
}
const getWeather = async (baseURLz, zipcode, baseURLa, apikey)=>{

  const res = await fetch(baseURLz+zipcode+baseURLa+apikey+'&units = imperial')
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
  }
}
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{

    const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    credentials: 'same-origin', 
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
  });

    try {
      const newData = await res.json();
      return newData;
    }catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    }
};
    const updateUI = async () => {
    const req = await fetch('/all');
    try{
      const allData = await req.json();
      document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = 'Date: '+allData.date;
      document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = 'Temperature: '+allData.temp+'°F';
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Feelings: '+allData.ures;
  
    }catch(error){
      console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```

and this is the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Weather Journal</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700|Ranga:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
 <body>
<div id = "app">
  <div class ="holder headline">
    Weather Journal App
  </div>
  <div class ="holder zip">
    <label for="zip">Enter Zipcode here</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip" placeholder="enter zip code here">
  </div>
  <div class ="holder feel">
    <label for="feelings">How are you feeling today?</label>
    <textarea class= "myInput" id="feelings" placeholder="Enter your feelings here" rows="9" cols="50"></textarea>
    <button id="generate" type = "submit"> Generate </button>
  </div>
  <div class ="holder entry">
    <div class = "title">Most Recent Entry</div>
   <div id = "entryHolder">
    <div id = "date"></div> 
   <div id = "temp"></div>
   <div id = "content"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

please i want to figure out where is the problem causing this to happen.

Comment: You have html element with id = "generate" ?

Comment: yes i have i will include the html

Comment: Just replace `.then(updateUI())` with `.then(updateUI)`. Right now, you're calling it before the request is complete. Let the `then` call it itself. **Edit:** You may also want to `return postData('/all'`, to make sure the request is done before the `then` is executed